# Ability to unlock phone in read only mode (and multiple phone users)

Tags: permissions, multi-user, password-protection, authentication, reading

Wouldn't it be nice if Android and Android apps catered towards the ability to unlock your phone on read only mode.

In this way, you can give your phone to someone (for instance, a family member), and they can read all of your stuff, but, through app support, via app APIs (with designation), the user cannot delete your stuff when the phone is unlocked in this way.

If the user is given permission, they may also send email or WhatsApp messages (and, this, also supported in the system and app API, is done on a per app basis).

This can be done by the main user, who controls auxiliary users and sets permissions for them.

This is also important for users that need their personal space on their phone but have a caregiver that manages some of the stuff on their phone for them.

Such users may also easily unlock the phone though an onscreen fingerprint control, for much ease, in the case of assisted users, making breaking into their phone impossible (without gaining access to their hand), and this level of control, in this manner, would not only be possible, but also practical.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: So Android Enthusiasts can't help with feature requests, see a similar [meta SO post answer on what questions go where](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3974/159081). Do realize that Android does allow for multiple user accounts like ['Guest' account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3974/159081) but realize that if the primary user has a plain text password file and hands over the device to a child/aide/friend that person can still read the file. Perhaps before the OS was released you could have added in such APIs but I would think about what an evil person could do to exploit them.